# Dual Boot on Lenovo yoga 2 13

Tags: dual-boot

I recently installed ubuntu on a lenovo yoga 2 13 alongside the pre-installed windows 8(updated to 10). Both OS works fine, the only problem is I have to switch between lagacy(for ubuntu) and UEFI(for windows) in the BIOS during start up to load either OS. If this is standard, I'm fine with it but my question is;

Is there a way to fix this so I don't have to enter into the BIOS everytime I'm changing OS?

OK, It does show Windows OS on the lagacy start up, but it gives error msg, and only ubuntu loads up.

Thanks